# How to Filter for Non-Standard Columns in Sharepoint REST Api

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to determine which columns in a SP List or document library were custom generated by the user? I'm essentially trying to recreate SharePoint's front end in my app, and I want to add columns to my table just like if the user adds a column in SP. My issue is determining which columns are non-standard.

I already know how to get properties for list items/files and I can see my user generated columns in the response. I'm just looking for **is there a way to filter for only non-standard columns?**

**User Generated Column in SP**

[image]

**Column in Results (as well as all other default fields)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can use the REST API below to get the custom fields from a custom list.

```
http://sp2013/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('CustomList')/fields?$select=Title&$filter=FromBaseType eq false
```

For document library use this.

```
http://sp2013/sites/team/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/fields?$select=Title&$filter=FromBaseType eq false and Hidden eq false and CanBeDeleted eq true and substringof('SourceID="{',SchemaXml)
```

Comment: Nice and simple, although won't work for me since I'm using a document library and not a list

Comment: I modify the reply above, you can check it.

Comment: Still getting a `Cannot find resource for the request fields.` 404 error

Answer (score 0):

I find the most reliable way to determine whether field is *built-in*  or it a *custom one* is to utilize [`SPField.SourceId` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms438011(v%3Doffice.14)):

> Gets either the namespace that defines a built-in field or, if it a
>   custom field, the GUID that identifies the list or Web site where it
>   was created.

In case of SharePoint REST API, `SourceId` property is not exposed but could be extracted from `SchemaXml` property

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve all the custom fields from a list:

```
https://site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/fields?$select=InternalName&$filter=substringof('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3',SchemaXml) eq false
```

Once the list of field is retrieved, the values of list items could be retrieved by specifying field names in $select expression:

```
https://site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items?$select=<fieldname1>,<fieldname2>
```

**Update**

The encountered error

> Cannot find resource for the request fields

tells that requested resource(library in this case) could not be found, make sure to provide *library title* for `getbytitle` method:

```
https://site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')

                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: What about with using a Document library, since you don't have access to the fields property?

Comment: @MattL. no difference, the same technique applies to library, both list and library  resources expose fields and list items

Comment: Interesting because I'm getting a 404 error saying `Cannot find resource for the request fields.`

Comment: @MattL., the answer has been updated, apparently this error occurs due to invalid request